# Track individual clicks for content delivery

Tags: email, content, track

We are looking into Salesforce Content Delivery (CD) to send out marketing material, white papers to our clients. However, CD only creates a unique link per file and reports how many views that file has had.

This isn't granular/detailed enough for our needs.

Is there any way to track WHO clicked on the link (they will be non-SF users so tracking will be my email address)? Definitely this is not possible within CD - but any way to build something around it to facilitate these requirements using the basic Salesforce licence (ie. not email studio, mail chimp, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we had to build a completely custom solution using sites.com